# Converting if/else to JS/jQuery

Tags: javascript, php

What I need is to first change the `PHP` array to `JS` array:

```
$url = "web.com";

<script type="text/javascript">
  var url = <?php echo json_encode($url); ?>;
</script>
```

Now with `Javascript`/`JQuery` I need to do this action:

```
if(strpos($url, "com") !== false){
  echo "<p><b style="background-color:blue; color:white;">TEST</b></p>";
}
else{
  echo "<p><b style="background-color:yellow; color:white;">TEST</b></p>";
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `$url` is a string. Not an array/json

Comment: If `$url` is not a JSON, you should probably not use `json_encode($url);`

Comment: @Aenadon — It's a string. If you run it through `json_encode` then the output will be valid JSON. Since JSON was designed as a subset of JavaScript, it will also be a safely escaped JavaScript string literal.

Comment: @Eddie — JSON is what you get **out** of `json_encode`, not what you put into it.

Comment: @Aenadon — You seem to be confusing `json_encode` with `json_decode`.

Comment: "What I need is to first change the PHP array to JS array" — You seem to be confusing strings and arrays. `$url` is a string. Your PHP uses `strpos` which is a function designed to operate on strings. You have no arrays anywhere in your code.

Comment: This question is really too broad for Stackoverflow. There's nothing really complicated here, but the question gives the impression of being asked with the mindset of "I know nothing about JavaScript and can't be bothered to learn anything, now spoonfeed me code". You should read an introductory tutorial and [do some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) before asking here. Alternatively, you could hire a freelancer to write the code for you.

Comment: @chriss.abdirahin — It would be a waste of time to write another tutorial introducing the very basics of JavaScript.

Comment: @Quentin whoops, yes, I was a little abstracted with my thoughts when I read this. Sorry.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
var url = location.href;

var child = document.createElement('div');
if(url.indexOf("com") != -1) {  
  str = '<p><b style="background-color:blue; color:white;">TEST</b></p>'; 
} else {
  str = '<p><b style="background-color:yellow; color:white;">TEST</b></p>';
}

child.innerHTML = str;
child = child.firstChild;
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(child);
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```